# Identifying and Replacing formatted date range from an html string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a following html string in which a date range has to be replaced.

```js
 var htmlStr = "<strong>1-Mar-2015</strong>"+
     "<span> to </span>"+
     "<strong>15-Feb-2016</strong><br>"+
     "<span>by </span>"+
     "<strong>Week</strong><br>"+
     "<span>Key</span>"+
     "<span> is </span>"+
     "<strong>Key Value</strong><br>"+
     "<span>Type</span>"+
     "<span> is </span>"+
     "<strong>Report</strong>"+
     "<span> or </span>"+
     "<strong>Incident</strong><br>"+
     "<span>SomeKey</span>"+
     "<span> is </span>"+
     "<strong>SomeValue</strong>";
```

I want to replace the date range with some specific date range.
For now i am breaking the html string with br tag to divide different properties and trying to replace the content of first and second strong tag.

I am looking for possible Regex solution to replace date range.

The js code flow is as follows:

```
var startdate = '2-Jun-2012';//selected from dom
var enddate = '24-Sept-2014';//selected from dom
for(var i = 0; i < IDList.length; i++ ) {
    var htmstr = loadHtmlDataFromServer(IDList[i]); //will get html type content from server
    //if startdate and enddate value exist, update htmstr
    CreateModal(htmlstr, IDList[i]);
}
```

Comment: you know for fact the the date will be display in `strong` tags?

Comment: yes it will be in strong tags and its a string.

Comment: you can try `$("strong:eq(0)").text(startDate)` and `$("strong:eq(1)").text(endDate)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged this jQuery:

```
var $html = $(hmtlstr),$dates=$html.find("strong");
$dates.eq(0).text(newFromDateString);
$dates.eq(1).text(newToDateString);
```

Comment: Yes we can do that, +1 for the solution, but i was thinking of using string manipulation...
won't it be better.

Comment: It us not recommended to do string manipulation on html - especially not if you have a Dom manipulating library loaded anyway